# Can't force webkit to render with GPU

Tags: css, rendering, gpu, css-transitions

So, I can't use `scale()` because it requires too much power from GPU when I render my 3200x3200 territory. So I decided to go with `height/width/left/top`, as I suspected it requires less performance and even FF can render it very good.

**Problem:** When I transition `width/height/top/left` `-webkit-` won't use GPU for rendering anymore, even if I add `translate3d()` or `translateZ()` to `-wbkit-transform` values.

**Question:**

1. What can I do improve performance in Chrome or trigger GPU render?

Answer (score 0):

try this to force GPU rendering:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
```

Comment: It seems, that no matter what, if only non transform css is render, then GPU isn't triggered. So I'm using GreenSock Tween's for now. It's not as good as clean GPU rendered, but it's better then plain jQUery.

Comment: ho I know what you mean..yes, Chrome is REALLY bad with these stuff...but using GreenShock is making your page load very slow, because their code is bloated like...I can't think of someone fat enough. it has it's price

Comment: While it is quite big, in my case `quality > performance`. In addition to that I use MVC 4 bundles for source file caching.